# Get Jenkins Metrics data through API

Tags: api, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

What I need with the API call

[image: What I need with the API call]

I need the timeline info for each of the builds via the API call for Jenkins metrics plugin. I am using a web API to get data for my jobs in my jenkins. However, calling `$JenkinsUrl/metrics/APIkey` is leading me nowhere. Any idea how can I achieve the information?

Comment: More precisely, how to target each build for the jobs and get the data? The only API call I know as of now is `$JENKINS_URL/metrics/$METRICS_API_KEY` but I can't find a way how to make this target a specific build and get the timeline info for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All three bits of timeline info for each build (queue time, building time, total time) are available via the "get build" API.

On the screen where it shows "8.1 sec waiting in the queue" etc, click on the "REST API" link in the page footer, then "JSON API", then add `&depth=2` to the end of the resulting API URL.

note, if you're searching for specific values in the API json, that the times will be in milliseconds. after you parse the json, build time is under the "duration" property, and the other two are in the array under the "actions" property. for me, it was the third element of the array, but that may vary (find the one with _class "jenkins.metrics.impl.TimeInQueueAction"):

```
{
  "_class": "jenkins.metrics.impl.TimeInQueueAction",
  "queuingDurationMillis": 16,
  "totalDurationMillis": 4365
}
```

so in my example the build time was 4349 and the queue time was 16, so the total time was 4349 + 16 = 4365 milliseconds.

Instead of adding `&depth=2` to the end of the url, you might be able to get exactly the three values you want by appending this to the url: `&tree=duration,actions[queuingDurationMillis,totalDurationMillis]`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. However, I found the above said explanation on some thread after asking the question here, but I was unaware on how to find the build time still. This makes my work complete. Can't thank enough :)